# Unable to configure knife on windows 7

Tags: windows, chef-infra, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed chefDK 0.15 on windows 7, 
copied *.pem files from etc/chef-server to my windows machine in %USERPROFILE%.chef\
Now while I'm trying to configure knife using the following command,
`knife configure -i`

It creates the knife.rb file but fails to create a user.pem file and the out put is as below,

```
    C:\Users\ECSAdmin\.chef>knife configure -i
Overwrite C:/Users/ECSAdmin/.chef/knife.rb? (Y/N) Y
Please enter the chef server URL: [https://TRAINw7X64VC04.training.local:443]
tps://EVALCHEFLIN01.ecsemea.com:443
Please enter a name for the new user: [ECSAdmin] amir
Please enter the existing admin name: [admin] admin
Please enter the location of the existing admin's private key: [/etc/chef-serv
/admin.pem] "C:\Users\ECSAdmin\.chef\admin.pem"
Please enter the validation clientname: [chef-validator]
Please enter the location of the validation key: [/etc/chef-server/chef-valida
r.pem] "C:\Users\ECSAdmin\.chef\chef-validator.pem"
Please enter the path to a chef repository (or leave blank):
Creating initial API user...
Please enter a password for the new user:
WARNING: IF YOU ARE USING CHEF SERVER 12+, PLEASE FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTIONS UNDE
knife user create --help.
You only passed a single argument to knife user create.
For backwards compatibility, when only a single argument is passed,
knife user create assumes you want Open Source 11 Server user creation.
knife user create for Open Source 11 Server is being deprecated.
Open Source 11 Server user commands now live under the knife osc_user namespac

For backwards compatibility, we will forward this request to knife osc_user cr
te.
If you are using an Open Source 11 Server, please use that command to avoid th
 warning.
FATAL: Cannot find subcommand for: 'osc_user configure -i'
Available subcommands: (for details, knife SUB-COMMAND --help)

** BOOTSTRAP COMMANDS **
knife bootstrap [SSH_USER@]FQDN (options)
knife bootstrap windows ssh FQDN (options)
knife bootstrap windows winrm FQDN (options)

** CLIENT COMMANDS **
knife client bulk delete REGEX (options)
knife client create CLIENTNAME (options)
knife client delete CLIENT (options)
knife client edit CLIENT (options)
Usage: C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife (options)
knife client key delete CLIENT KEYNAME (options)
knife client key edit CLIENT KEYNAME (options)
knife client key list CLIENT (options)
knife client key show CLIENT KEYNAME (options)
knife client list (options)
knife client reregister CLIENT (options)
knife client show CLIENT (options)

** CONFIGURE COMMANDS **
knife configure (options)
knife configure client DIRECTORY

** COOKBOOK COMMANDS **
knife cookbook bulk delete REGEX (options)
knife cookbook create COOKBOOK (options)
knife cookbook delete COOKBOOK VERSION (options)
knife cookbook download COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife cookbook list (options)
knife cookbook metadata COOKBOOK (options)
knife cookbook metadata from FILE (options)
knife cookbook show COOKBOOK [VERSION] [PART] [FILENAME] (options)
knife cookbook test [COOKBOOKS...] (options)
knife cookbook upload [COOKBOOKS...] (options)

** COOKBOOK SITE COMMANDS **
knife cookbook site download COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife cookbook site install COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife cookbook site list (options)
knife cookbook site search QUERY (options)
knife cookbook site share COOKBOOK [CATEGORY] (options)
knife cookbook site show COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife cookbook site unshare COOKBOOK

** DATA BAG COMMANDS **
knife data bag create BAG [ITEM] (options)
knife data bag delete BAG [ITEM] (options)
knife data bag edit BAG ITEM (options)
knife data bag from file BAG FILE|FOLDER [FILE|FOLDER..] (options)
knife data bag list (options)
knife data bag show BAG [ITEM] (options)

** DECRYPT COMMANDS **
knife decrypt VAULT ITEM [VALUES] (options)

** EC2 COMMANDS **
knife ec2 amis ubuntu DISTRO [TYPE] (options)

** ENCRYPT COMMANDS **
knife encrypt create VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)
knife encrypt delete VAULT ITEM (options)
knife encrypt remove VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)
knife encrypt rotate keys VAULT ITEM (options)
knife encrypt update VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)

** ENVIRONMENT COMMANDS **
knife environment compare [ENVIRONMENT..] (options)
knife environment create ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife environment delete ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife environment edit ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife environment from file FILE [FILE..] (options)
knife environment list (options)
knife environment show ENVIRONMENT (options)

** EXEC COMMANDS **
knife exec [SCRIPT] (options)

** HELP COMMANDS **
knife help [list|TOPIC]

** INDEX COMMANDS **
knife index rebuild (options)

** JOB COMMANDS **
knife job list
knife job output <job id> <node> [<node> ...]
knife job start <command> [<node> <node> ...]
knife job status <job id>

** KNIFE COMMANDS **
Usage: C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife (options)

** NODE COMMANDS **
knife node bulk delete REGEX (options)
knife node create NODE (options)
knife node delete NODE (options)
knife node edit NODE (options)
knife node environment set NODE ENVIRONMENT
knife node from file FILE (options)
knife node list (options)
knife node run_list add [NODE] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife node run_list remove [NODE] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife node run_list set NODE ENTRIES (options)
knife node show NODE (options)
knife node status [<node> <node> ...]

** NULL COMMANDS **
knife null

** OSC COMMANDS **
knife osc_user create USER (options)
knife osc_user delete USER (options)
knife osc_user edit USER (options)
knife osc_user list (options)
knife osc_user reregister USER (options)
knife osc_user show USER (options)

** PATH-BASED COMMANDS **
knife delete [PATTERN1 ... PATTERNn]
knife deps PATTERN1 [PATTERNn]
knife diff PATTERNS
knife download PATTERNS
knife edit [PATTERN1 ... PATTERNn]
knife list [-dfR1p] [PATTERN1 ... PATTERNn]
knife show [PATTERN1 ... PATTERNn]
knife upload PATTERNS
knife xargs [COMMAND]

** RAW COMMANDS **
knife raw REQUEST_PATH

** RECIPE COMMANDS **
knife recipe list [PATTERN]

** REHASH COMMANDS **
knife rehash

** ROLE COMMANDS **
knife role bulk delete REGEX (options)
knife role create ROLE (options)
knife role delete ROLE (options)
knife role edit ROLE (options)
knife role env_run_list add [ROLE] [ENVIRONMENT] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife role env_run_list clear [ROLE] [ENVIRONMENT]
knife role env_run_list remove [ROLE] [ENVIRONMENT] [ENTRIES]
knife role env_run_list replace [ROLE] [ENVIRONMENT] [OLD_ENTRY] [NEW_ENTRY]
knife role env_run_list set [ROLE] [ENVIRONMENT] [ENTRIES]
knife role from file FILE [FILE..] (options)
knife role list (options)
knife role run_list add [ROLE] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife role run_list clear [ROLE]
knife role run_list remove [ROLE] [ENTRY]
knife role run_list replace [ROLE] [OLD_ENTRY] [NEW_ENTRY]
knife role run_list set [ROLE] [ENTRIES]
knife role show ROLE (options)

** SEARCH COMMANDS **
knife search INDEX QUERY (options)

** SERVE COMMANDS **
knife serve (options)

** SPORK COMMANDS **
knife spork bump COOKBOOK [major|minor|patch|manual]
knife spork check COOKBOOK (options)
knife spork data bag create BAG [ITEM] (options)
knife spork data bag delete BAG [ITEM] (options)
knife spork data bag edit BAG ITEM (options)
knife spork data bag from file BAG FILE|FOLDER [FILE|FOLDER..] (options)
knife spork environment check ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife spork environment create ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife spork environment delete ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife spork environment edit ENVIRONMENT (options)
knife spork environment from file FILENAME (options)
knife spork info
knife spork node create NODE (options)
knife spork node delete NODE (options)
knife spork node edit NODE (options)
knife spork node from file FILE (options)
knife spork node run_list add [NODE] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife spork node run_list add [NODE] [ENTRY[,ENTRY]] (options)
knife spork node run_list set NODE ENTRIES (options)
knife spork omni COOKBOOK (options)
knife spork promote ENVIRONMENT COOKBOOK (options)
knife spork role create ROLE (options)
knife spork role delete ROLENAME (options)
knife spork role edit ROLENAME (options)
knife spork role from file FILENAME (options)
knife spork upload [COOKBOOKS...] (options)

** SSH COMMANDS **
knife ssh QUERY COMMAND (options)

** SSL COMMANDS **
knife ssl check [URL] (options)
knife ssl fetch [URL] (options)

** STATUS COMMANDS **
knife status QUERY (options)

** SUPERMARKET COMMANDS **
knife supermarket download COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife supermarket install COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife supermarket list (options)
knife supermarket search QUERY (options)
knife supermarket share COOKBOOK (options)
knife supermarket show COOKBOOK [VERSION] (options)
knife supermarket unshare COOKBOOK

** TAG COMMANDS **
knife tag create NODE TAG ...
knife tag delete NODE TAG ...
knife tag list NODE

** USER COMMANDS **
knife user create USERNAME DISPLAY_NAME FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME EMAIL PASSWORD (o
ions)
knife user delete USER (options)
knife user edit USER (options)
knife user key create USER (options)
knife user key delete USER KEYNAME (options)
knife user key edit USER KEYNAME (options)
knife user key list USER (options)
knife user key show USER KEYNAME (options)
knife user list (options)
knife user reregister USER (options)
knife user show USER (options)

** VAULT COMMANDS **
knife vault create VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)
knife vault decrypt VAULT ITEM [VALUES] (options)
knife vault delete VAULT ITEM (options)
knife vault download VAULT ITEM PATH (options)
knife vault edit VAULT ITEM (options)
knife vault isvault VAULT ITEM (options)
knife vault itemtype VAULT ITEM (options)
knife vault list (options)
knife vault refresh VAULT ITEM
knife vault remove VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)
knife vault rotate all keys
knife vault rotate keys VAULT ITEM (options)
knife vault show VAULT [ITEM] [VALUES] (options)
knife vault update VAULT ITEM VALUES (options)

** WINDOWS COMMANDS **
knife windows cert generate FILE_PATH (options)
knife windows cert install CERT [CERT] (options)
knife bootstrap windows winrm FQDN (options)
knife bootstrap windows ssh FQDN (options)
knife winrm QUERY COMMAND (options)
knife wsman test QUERY (options)
knife windows listener create (options)

** WINRM COMMANDS **
knife winrm QUERY COMMAND (options)

** WSMAN COMMANDS **
knife wsman test QUERY (options)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable Bootstrap chef client on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161062/unable-bootstrap-chef-client-on-windows-7)

Comment: @coderanger no it isn't as the question I have asked is based on workstation configuration whereas `Unable Bootstrap chef client on windows 7 ` this is based on client installation from workstation.

Comment: They are most likely the same underlying problem, and thus one question.

Comment: @coderanger I thought those two are different configurations,
well do you have any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: As I mentioned on the other question: stop trying to use a Chef Server 11 workflow with newer ChefDK and/or knife commands. You can find the instructions to set up the initial org and user at https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html#standalone